# When flying domestically in Thailand, which (origin airport, destination airport) results in a quarantine?

Tags: air-travel, thailand, covid-19, quarantine

When flying domestically within Thailand, which (origin airport, destination airport) results in a quarantine, and if so what's the quarantine conditions?

I'm mostly interested in origin airport = BKK/DMK or destination airport = BKK/DMK.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Richard Barrow's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1267627629613445120) ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/tqxfu), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200602181211/https://twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1267627629613445120)) on 2020-06-02:

> Although Phuket has opened its land and sea borders, it’s not the best time to visit as there is a mandatory 14-day quarantine on visitors arriving from eight risky provinces -- Bangkok, Nonthaburi, Narathiwat, Yala, Krabi, Prachin Buri, Samut Prakan and Chiang Mai.