# Is there any website or service for showing countries / regions open for travel during Covid-19 restrictions?

Tags: online-resources, covid-19, flight-search-engines, accommodation-search-engines

As countries and regions open up from lockdown, I was wondering if there's an online tool that can highlight which places a person is free to travel to based on:

1. Passports held
2. Current residency / residency status
3. Destination country / region
4. Transit countries
5. Local restrictions at destination (e.g., is it essential travel only, Covid-19 testing requirements, are hotels open or is it living with family only)

Comment: Given how fluid the situation is and how different countries are handling it, it might be easier if you have a specific country in mind and *then* check their procedures on their official website. I'd be wary of any third party site not having the most up to date info.

Comment: Not an answer, but I guess this question here should be the answer to your question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157147/what-if-any-countries-are-either-open-to-or-have-set-definitive-plans-to-allow

Comment: I have seen a list in the Guardian website, where there are mistakes (being in the country mentioned I can see they are not right, but it is because our government is not clear about whether foreign tourists are welcome) I do not trust any online list to be right for every combination of countries.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Sometimes we're open to various countries depending on which ones are possible to narrow down the choices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! I actually [just posted about this](https://beatthatflight.com.au/index.php/2020/06/09/iata-has-released-an-interactive-map-which-tells-you-which-countries-are-open-for-travel/) - IATA has released [an interactive map](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) that shows you the countries, restrictions, etc, based on Timatic data, as Frank has said in his answer.

However, you can also look at [Travelbans.org](https://travelbans.org), which is another site you can use which gives you continuously updated information on travel restrictions for every country.

Comment: Thanks, the interactive map (released a few weeks ago, I forgot when exactly) isn't conditioned on the OP's criteria though, e.g. we can't indicate one's citizenship or provenance country. Also doesn't indicate local restrictions on the map. So we typically have to go through countries manually, which isn't great.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, such website / database / service covering your five points doesn't exist.

For your first 4 points, one typically resort at manually going through https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm and ideally trying to double check the information with the country's websites and airlines, which is error-prone and inefficient. For your last point, see [Where can I find an up-to-date list of COVID-19-related curfews and business closures in different countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155345/1810). Interestingly, even though travel-related businesses are sinking, they often don't try much to make it easier for the  few remaining travelers to navigate through covid-19 restrictions.

To make it even trickier, a country may have different covid-19 rules for different areas, e.g. [When flying domestically in Thailand, which (origin airport, destination airport) results in a quarantine?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157464/1810).

Also, https://www.restrictions.info/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810010407/https://www.restrictions.info/)):

[image]

And https://www.worldnomads.com/travel-safety/worldwide/worldwide-travel-alerts ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812034502/https://www.worldnomads.com/travel-safety/worldwide/worldwide-travel-alerts)).

Answer (score 2):

[Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/travel-restrictions) has published an interactive map to show which countries are open.

The map (as of 2nd July 2020):

> [image: map]

And this is what the colour codes mean:

> [image: colours]